# Eclipse Java formatter: add newline before array closing brace ONLY if that wraps

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I setup my formatter to
**Line Wrapping → Wrapping Settings → Other Expressions → Array Initializer:**

> "Wrap all elements, every element on a new line"

and
**New Lines:**

> "Before closing braces of array initializers"

What I get is this:

```java
@AnnotationWithLongArray({
       "item",
       "item",
       "item",
       "item",
       "item",
       "item"
})
```

and this

```java
@AnnotationWithShortArray({ "item", "item"
})
```

First one is what I want, but for second case I'd like the newline not being added before closing bracket, if array doesn't wrap

```java
@AnnotationWithShortArray({ "item", "item" })
```

Is it Eclipse capable of this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

- **Braces** - on array initializer, check `same line`
- **New Lines** - uncheck

  - after closing brace initializer
  - before closing brace initializer

This is what I get.

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int[] b = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,
        3,4,5,6};
```

**Edit:** Per review I just noticed that you wanted the wrapped array to have the closing brace on a new line.  I checked the export `xml` file and could not find anything like `insert line on wrap before closing brace on array initializer` or any other similar construct or pair of constructs.

One possible alternative is to selectively turn formatting off and then on once the format for a particular item is set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately as you already noticed that output is not my goal.
`insert_new_line_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer` seems to accept only a value between `INSERT` and `DO_NOT_INSERT` instead of `SEPARATE_LINES_IF_WRAPPED` and similar like parentheses-related options do.

Comment: I modified my answer for future readers.  You can turn the formatting on and off multiple times.  You can even change the commands to do so.  This would permit you to manually format the initializer and then ensure it doesn't get changed when reformatting.  Those options are at the bottom of the edit window.

Comment: Yes but that's not a solution, considering that you should add one line before and one after every occurrence of any array you don't want to be formatted.
And on top of that, it would turn off EVERY formatting for those lines, AFAIK it's not possible to "granularize" format disabling.

Comment: Not it isn't a real solution.  But you can turn formatting on and off as many times as you want.  So some sections will be formatted and others won't. I know because I have done it.